# Поиск и замена символов в textBox

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как искать в textbox определённые символы и заменять их на другие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У стринга есть метод Replace(Что менять, на что менять), у textbox есть свойство text.

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace('a','b'); // поменяет в тексте все а на b.
```

Comment: спасибо!!Всё намного проще чем я думал!

Comment: Привёдённый код исходную строку не изменит, он вернёт новую.

Comment: угу, строки они как бы immutable